# Append to an array from another function?

Tags: arrays, go

I have this code in which I am appending to an array of a struct in one function. The change does not appear in the other function.

```
type my struct{
arr []int
}

func New_my() *my {
  m := new (my)
  return m
}

func (m my) Dosomething(){
  m.arr = append(m.arr,1)
  m.arr = append(m.arr,2)
  m.arr = append(m.arr,3)
}

func (m my) Dosomethingelse(){
  fmt.Println(m.arr)
}

func main(){

  m:= New_my()
  m.Dosomething()
  m.Dosomethingelse()
}
```

The output is:

```
[]
```

Please, explain what is happening? Why does the change not appear in the array?

Comment: Nitpick: You code contains zero arrays (but some slices). I'd like to recommend the whole Go tour http://tour.golang.org/ .

Comment: I know it's a slice. I should have named it like that. But the problem was why was it not changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to go you should totally do the [tour of go](https://tour.golang.org/) and the [effective go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) document. Go is a new language and with a strange combination of ideas so the official documentation is the best place to start.

First of all you are using a slice not an array. (Read [this](https://tour.golang.org/#31) to understand slices)

The error in your code is because Dosomething() is defined for `my` instead of `*my`. This is explained [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#methods).

Just change it to:

```
func (m *my) Dosomething(){
  m.arr = append(m.arr,1)
  m.arr = append(m.arr,2)
  m.arr = append(m.arr,3)
}
```

In go everything is passed by value so in your code you are passing a copy of the struct to the function `Dosomething()`, and because the capacity of the slice is 0, the `append` function creates a new underlying array and returns a reference to it, and when yo do:

```
m.arr = append(...)
```

the new slice (using the new array) is lost because it is stored in m that is a copy of the original struct, if m were a `*my` the new slice would replace the previous in the arr property.

Comment: "Go is a new language and with a strange combination of ideas", I had to laugh because the pass-by-value issue here isn't new, its very much like C. :)

Comment: @voidlogic I didn't mean that is new, but in general go is like c plus a bunch of ideas from newer languages. So no harm done in reading the language doc.

Answer (score 0):

In Go everything is passed by value, including the this/self/me/`m` argument provided to receivers (aka methods).

In Go if something does not appear to be passed by value, then either a pointer to it, or a struct containing a pointer (as is the case for string, slice, etc) is being passed.

That means right now your `DoSomething` gets **a copy** of the self-object and appends to that.

So in this case Topo is correct, you just need to change `DoSomething()` to pass its self/this/`m` argument as a pointer.

```
func (m *my) Dosomething(){
  m.arr = append(m.arr,1)
  m.arr = append(m.arr,2)
  m.arr = append(m.arr,3)
}
```

I assume this is toy code, but a couple of notes:

You could write this more efficiently as:

```
func (m *my) Dosomething(){
  m.arr = append(m.arr,[]int{1,2,3}...)
}
```

And it would be more idiomatic to rename `New_my()` to `newMy()`